# How to test full chrome extension with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I am creating a chrome extension. I need to test it using some tool. The extension is using a popup and a content script and also another iframe which is embedded by content script. I want to test everything combined. But the problem is that I am unable to open and access the `popup` if I visit some desired. And if I go only to `popup.html` then I can't test the extension on desired url.

Is there any way to open the popup of particular extension right from url using puppeteer.

Here is my code

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import path from "path";


(async () => {
   // Path to extension folder
   const paths =
      "C:\\Users\\mahee\\Documents\\freelancer\\bug-reporter\\frontend";
   chrome: try {
      console.log("==>Open Browser");
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
         headless: false,
         args: [
            `--disable-extensions-except=${paths}`,
            `--load-extension=${paths}`,
            `--window-size=800,600`,
         ],
      });

      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto("https://www.google.com/");
      //How here I want to open the popup only as popup on the given url not on separate page.
   } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
   }
})();
```

I am online. If any further information required please ask.

The steps of the test will be like below.

- open popup
- Login to some account from popup
- If login is successful. Popup will show "Take Screenshot" button
- User click on that and popup closes
- User uses mouse to select some area.
- After that he will be shown an iframe in which he will edit the image
- Finally submit it to some api

Comment: what exactly are you going to test?

Comment: If you're not sure, this might help: https://walrus.ai/blog/2021/02/simple-steps-for-testing-a-chrome-extension-in-puppeteer/

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad I have added the steps of the test which I have to do.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad The link you gave is for testing the popup only. I want to test popup from content script not as a separate html page.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to amend your extension so that its popup to be opened automatically after loading any webpage.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).